# custom MessageBox like iPhone

Tags: qt

Is it possible to customize the default QMessageBox in Qt, so that it'll look like iPhone's messageBox control.
 And also is it possible to display it in the middle of the screen like that of iPhone.

Thanks...

Comment: Could you put a snapshot or a diagram of what you want, it would help anyone willing to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom widget looks like iPhone message box, But existing message box you can't customize i think so..
existing message box, is as per Nokia standards which display by default at the bottom of your screen.

Comment: Exactly... I just want to customize the existing MessageBox which displays by default at the bottom of the screen...Infact I want this to be placed at the center of the screen... Is it possible in any ways???

Comment: better create a custom widget with a gray back ground color and a button image over it and display at the center of screen.. handle image click as the button press.. i tried to set the geometry to Qmessagebox its not taking..